# AspectJ Compiler on Eclipse Photon - Compilation issues

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj

I have several Java Maven projects built over the years that leverage AspectJ.

All projects compile correctly on both Eclipse Neon and Maven command line.

On Photon, however, I receive lots of error messages all originating from the inability to compile the AspecJ code. For example:

```
pointcut test() : execution(@org.junit.Test * *(..));
```

causes

```
pointcut cannot be resolved to a type
```

and

```
before() : test() {
    localLog(thisJoinPoint).info(format("*** Test execution @ %s", describe(thisJoinPointStaticPart)));
}
```

causes the errors:

```
thisJoinPoint cannot be resolved to a variable
```

and

```
thisJoinPointStaticPart cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix the compilation on Photon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a version of [AJDT](https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) compatible with Photon. I am still on Oxygen.2, have not tried Photon yet, but obviously there is no official AJDT release for Photon yet.

Next time maybe check plugin availability before you update. What I am seeing on the [download page](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/) is only a development build for Eclipse 4.8 with the update site

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/48/dev/update
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the hint, it really helped me out. However, there was a step more to take after installing AJDT. Found out there was another plugin conflicting with the AJ compiler. It was the Fuse feature of the JBoss Tools extension. Since we use it only for Widlfy support, I removed the extension then reinstalled choosing only the package we need. Note that this is valid for both Oxygen and Photon.